# Creating Custom RL Environment for Balancing a Ball on a Seesaw with Real Hardware

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Description:
I am new to reinforcement learning and attempting to train an RL agent to balance a ball on a seesaw using real hardware, not simulations. I face the challenge of creating a custom environment to represent this task.

Scenario:
Using a camera for detecting the ball position and an encoder to read the current angle of the seesaw. The detection model YOLOv8 works fine for ball detection, and an Arduino reads the current angle of the seesaw. Saving these values in SQlite Database. And controlling the angle of the seesaw with a bidirectional DC motor using PLCnext.

Implementation:
Aim is to use the current angle and ball position (continuously updated in an SQLite DB) as input to the RL model. The model's output will be the left and right movement, and the next action needs to be stored in the DB.

Difficulty:
Lacking the knowledge of how to set up the environment for this scenario. How can I customize existing environments to fit our use case?

Additional Context:
I'm using Python for my RL implementation and have a basic understanding of reinforcement learning concepts.
I have access to hardware components like motors and sensors for controlling and monitoring the seesaw and ball movements.

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I already have tried cartpole-v1 environment from OpenAI gym but not able to customize it according to the requirement.